# Powershell -Match operator only finding first match

Tags: powershell

```
"This is **bold** and this is also **BOLD**,finally this is also **Bold**" -match '\*\*.*?\*\*'
```

Finds only the first match

```
$Matches.count
```

Returns only `1`

Doing the same thing with `-Replace` Finds all matches in the string:

```
"This is **bold** and this is also **BOLD**,finally this is also **Bold**" -replace '\*\*.*?\*\*', 'Substring'
```

It matches and replaces all instances:

```
This is Substring and this is also Substring,finally this is also Substring
```

How do I get the `-Match` operator to find all matches and return them as arrays belonging to the `$Matches` variable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The **[`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator indeed only finds at most *one* match** in its input, invariably and by design, whereas [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) invariably finds and replaces *all* matches.
- **As of PowerShell 7.2.x, you need to use the underlying .NET APIs directly in order to find *multiple* matches**, namely the  **[`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches)** method.

  - [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) proposes introducing a `-matchall` operator to provide a PowerShell-native implementation - while the proposal has been green-lit, no one has stepped up to implement it yet.

```bash
[regex]::Matches(
  'This is **bold** and this is also **BOLD**,finally this is also **Bold**',
  '\*\*.*?\*\*'
).Value
```

Note that `[regex]::Matches()` returns a collection of [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instances, whose `.Value` property contains the matched text.